# XML files merging using robotframework rebot

Tags: xml, robotframework

I have tried merging 5 xml files using rebot --merge under a common test suite. Each xml file is generated each day.

Is it possible to get test case status i.e Pass or Fail for all 5 days one below other with date in the message field using rebot command?

Is there any other way to do it except the custom way of parsing the xml files?

Comment: What happened when you tried with `rebot --merge`?

Comment: when I used the rebot --merge its adds extra messages to the message field like "Reexecuted test has been merged"

Answer (score 1):

In short - no, you can't achieve what you want with rebot.
The `--merge` option overwrites execution results of the same cases/suites in different runs - what you currently see in the generated output  and html. Without it, these different runs will be concatenated.

But there is no option (at least to my knowledge, and) in the standard `rebot` tool, that will give side-by-side results comparison between executions.

Comment: I observed without merge I can see all reports in one report, but I dont want to se matching tags is there a way to eliminate these matching tags and put all steps together?